# VB.NET get next available drive letter

Tags: vb.net

I find a lot of VB6 examples out there, and a few C# examples, but no concrete solution in VB.NET. Simply put, I need to get the next available drive letter in as few lines of code as possible. Anyone have a good example?

Comment: General rule: learn C#. Any competent .NET programmer should understand both C# and .NET, better yet be competent in both and fluent in at least one. Then you will be able to understand C# code samples and translate them into VB without trouble.

Comment: there are plenty of converters out there. Try http://converter.telerik.com/ They do usually 95% of the job(sometimes more); you still usually have to tweak the result a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Public Function FindNextAvailableDriveLetter() As String
' build a string collection representing the alphabet
Dim alphabet As New StringCollection()

Dim lowerBound As Integer = Convert.ToInt16("a"C)
Dim upperBound As Integer = Convert.ToInt16("z"C)
For i As Integer = lowerBound To upperBound - 1
    Dim driveLetter As Char = ChrW(i)
    alphabet.Add(driveLetter.ToString())
Next

' get all current drives
Dim drives As DriveInfo() = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
For Each drive As DriveInfo In drives
    alphabet.Remove(drive.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower())
Next

If alphabet.Count > 0 Then
    Return alphabet(0)
Else
    Throw New ApplicationException("No drives available.")
End If
End Function
```

Source: [CodeKeep](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/8762dac9-64fe-4efc-bb08-512f40554baa.aspx)

Comment: No reason to put the argument of `Throw` in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Question: What is the "C" in the convert function? I see this a lot in different string functions.

Comment: I believe that's telling the convert function to treat "a" as a single char instead of a string.

Comment: Hm. This appears to work for me. Your computer already has an A: drive?

Comment: Can you watch the "drives" variable in debug, and see what drives it believes are already mapped?

Comment: @NickHeidke clearly your snippet is from http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/8762dac9-64fe-4efc-bb08-512f40554baa.aspx ; You should at least mention the source even if you did convert the code.

Comment: @NickHeidke Sorry I deleted that comment after I posted it because I found my mistake. Question though: in the first For Loop, aren't I stopping at 'Y' since I'm saying lowerBound To upperBound - 1? If 'Z' will be the upper bound, I don't think the -1 should be there. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bala R, thanks for tracking down the source of that snippet. I had copied it into my useful snippets folder and forgot to copy the hyperlink when I did so. I'll add that to the answer for future reference!

Comment: @JJD - I believe you are correct, we shouldn't need to do a -1 on the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got C# code, then put it through the [developerfusion coverter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) - that should get you close (although you'll probably have to tweak it).

Answer (score 0):

To list logical drives Try this....

Includes full code....

```
Imports System.Management

Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents w As ManagementEventWatcher
    Dim q As WqlEventQuery
    Delegate Sub LoadList()

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        w.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            q = New WqlEventQuery
            q.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM" & _
                        " __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 " & _
                        "WHERE TargetInstance isa ""Win32_LogicalDisk"""
            w = New ManagementEventWatcher(q)
            w.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        LoadDriveList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadDriveList()
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        Dim moReturn As Management.ManagementObjectCollection
        Dim moSearch As Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
        Dim mo As Management.ManagementObject

        moSearch = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

        moReturn = moSearch.Get
        For Each mo In moReturn
            ListBox1.Items.Add(mo("Name").ToString)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub w_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs) Handles w.EventArrived
        ListBox1.Invoke(New LoadList(AddressOf LoadDriveList))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The question is 4 months old and has an accepted answer. Why would you bother?!?